# Google Map or Bing Map Control for ASP.net Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps

Can you suggest some good Bing Map or Google Map control for ASP.net Webforms.
I have searched a lot on google and found few on codeplex but they perhaps are not stable.
Can any one of you suggest some good control whihc u have used earlier.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily create you own control for this. Both [google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) and [bing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx) have JavaScript API's

I have used this google one before though (without a problem) http://googlemap.codeplex.com/documentation